# Enabling https on Raspberry Local ports with reverse-proxy Caddy

Tags: docker-compose, https, raspberry-pi, localhost, caddy

I have in my raspberry pi 4 a docker-compose who creates an iotstack with influx, grafana, nodered, mosquitto and portainer. I want to enable https without a domain, just for my local devices.

I took the docker-compose from this tutorial:

[[Raspberry Pi IoT Server Tutorial: InfluxDB, MQTT, Grafana, Node-RED & Docker]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=_DO2wHI6JWQ&embeds_referring_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2F&embeds_referring_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com&source_ve_path=Mjg2NjY&feature=emb_logohttps://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=_DO2wHI6JWQ&embeds_referring_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2F&embeds_referring_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com&source_ve_path=Mjg2NjY&feature=emb_logo)

What I want to try (I am not even sure if this can be done) is to enable https on my localports so instead of accesing http://192.168.xxx.xxx:3000 (port for grafana p.e) I can use https://192.168.xxx.xxx(/grafana or 3000).
I know I cannot use Lets Encrypt certificates so I have been trying with mkcert certificates, I dont know what am I doing wrong, there is not much info about this so if everyone here can help I will really appreciate it.

I followed some steps of this tutorial but I changed some stuff since I am working with localhost ports and not an app or web like node.js
[[Docker Compose Local HTTPS with nginx or Caddy and mkcert]](https://codewithhugo.com/docker-compose-local-https/#:%7E:text=A%20solution%20to%20serve%20your%20Dockerized%20application%20on,Examples%20with%20Caddy%20and%20nginx%20are%20at%3A%20github.com%2FHugoDF%2Fdocker-compose-local-https)

docker-compose.yml :

```
 version: '3.6'

 networks:
   default:
     driver: bridge
     ipam:
       driver: default
   nextcloud:
     driver: bridge
     internal: true
     ipam:
       driver: default

 services:
   grafana:
     container_name: grafana
     image: grafana/grafana
     restart: unless-stopped
     user: "0"
     ports:
       - "3000:3000"
     environment:
       - TZ=Etc/UTC
       - GF_PATHS_DATA=/var/lib/grafana
       - GF_PATHS_LOGS=/var/log/grafana
     volumes:
       - ./volumes/grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana
       - ./volumes/grafana/log:/var/log/grafana
     healthcheck:
       test: ["CMD", "wget", "-O", "/dev/null", "http://localhost:3000"]
       interval: 30s
       timeout: 10s
       retries: 3
       start_period: 30s

   influxdb2:
     container_name: influxdb2
     image: "influxdb:latest"
     restart: unless-stopped
     environment:
       - TZ=Etc/UTC
       - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME=me
       - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD=mypassword
       - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG=myorg
       - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET=mybucket
       - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ADMIN_TOKEN=my-super-secret-auth-token
       - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_MODE=setup
     ports:
       - "8087:8086"
     volumes:
       - ./volumes/influxdb2/data:/var/lib/influxdb2
       - ./volumes/influxdb2/config:/etc/influxdb2
       - ./volumes/influxdb2/backup:/var/lib/backup
     healthcheck:
       test: ["CMD", "influx", "ping"]
       interval: 30s
       timeout: 10s
       retries: 3
       start_period: 30s

   mosquitto:
     container_name: mosquitto
     build:
       context: ./.templates/mosquitto/.
       args:
         - MOSQUITTO_BASE=eclipse-mosquitto:latest
     restart: unless-stopped
     environment:
       - TZ=${TZ:-Etc/UTC}
     ports:
       - "1883:1883"
     volumes:
       - ./volumes/mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config
       - ./volumes/mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
       - ./volumes/mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
       - ./volumes/mosquitto/pwfile:/mosquitto/pwfile 

   nodered:
     container_name: nodered
     build:
       context: ./services/nodered/.
       args:
         - DOCKERHUB_TAG=latest
         - EXTRA_PACKAGES=
     restart: unless-stopped
     user: "0"
     environment:
       - TZ=${TZ:-Etc/UTC}
     ports:
       - "1880:1880"
     volumes:
       - ./volumes/nodered/data:/data
       - ./volumes/nodered/ssh:/root/.ssh

   portainer-ce:
     container_name: portainer-ce
     image: portainer/portainer-ce
     restart: unless-stopped
     ports:
       - "8000:8000"
       - "9000:9000"
       # HTTPS
       - "9443:9443"
     volumes:
       - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
       - ./volumes/portainer-ce/data:/data

   caddy:
     image: "abiosoft/caddy:latest"
     volumes:
       - ./Caddyfile:/etc/Caddyfile
       - ./caddy/certs:/root/certs # to sync mkcert certificates to Caddy
     ports:
       - "443:2015"
     depends_on:
       - grafana
       - influxdb2
       - mosquitto
       - nodered
       - portainer-ce
```

And here is the Caddyfile

```
 http://192.168.xxx.xxx {
    # Enable TLS (HTTPS)
   tls /caddy/certs/iotstack.pem /caddy/certs/iotstack-key.pem

    #Rutas para acceder a los servicios
    reverse_proxy /grafana  grafana:3000
    reverse_proxy /influxdb2 influxdb2:8086
    reverse_proxy /mosquitto  mosquitto:1883
    reverse_proxy /nodered  nodered:1880
    reverse_proxy /portainer-ce  portainer-ce:9000
 }
```

When I execute this docker-compose all the ports are working perfectly for http but are not working with https, if I take a look to the logs related with caddy this is what I can see:

```
 caddy_1         | exec /bin/parent: exec format error
 iotstack_caddy_1 exited with code 1
```